# Aurelia Validation - Replacement for isValid in aurelia-validation@0.9.2

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In aurelia-validation version 0.6.8 you could check if the validation had passed or failed in the html using the isValid flag.

Set up the validation property like this:

```js
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';
@inject(Validation)

@customElement('base-content')
export class BaseContent {
    this.validation = validation;
    this.validator = this.validation.on(this).ensure('baseContent.Name').isNotEmpty();
}
```

And then use the isValid like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" disabled.bind="!validation.result.isValid">Sign In</button>
```

That used to work but I have recently upgraded the aurelia validation so I now have the following packages.
- aurelia-validation@0.9.2
- aurelia-validatejs@0.5.2

What I'm looking for is a way to replicate what I used to do but with the new packages.
This is the closest I could get but I don't want to be dirty checking when there used to be a nice alternative.

```js
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class Login {
    this.controller = controller;
}

get isValid(){
    if (this.controller.validate().length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" disabled.bind="!.isValid">Sign In</button>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `validation-errors` custom attribute to get a reference to the current errors array.  Objects in this array are shaped like this: `{ error: ValidationError, target: Element }`.

```html
<form validation-errors.bind="errors">
  ...
  ...
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" disabled.bind="errors.length">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That'll about do it, thanks. Is there a way to force the validation on initial load? The button stays enabled when a field with require() is empty.

Comment: Call the validate method on the controller

Comment: Yeah that was my first thought. Adding it to the bind method does the trick, I was calling it from activate. Thank you for the help.